# Redirecting the instruction pointer via stack overflow

Tags: c, overflow, stack-overflow

I have been reading *The Shellcoder's Handbook* (2e) and have been trying to reproduce the stack overflow experiment on pages 18-23.

I have this code

```
void return_input (void)
{
    char array[30];
    gets (array);
    printf(“%s\n”, array);
}
main()
{
    return_input();
    return 0;
}
```

Compile: `gcc -fno-stack-protector -o overflow overflow.c`

Dump of assembler code for function main:

```
0x080483ea <main+0>:  push %ebp
0x080483eb <main+1>:  mov  %esp,%ebp
0x080483ed <main+3>:  call 0x80483c4 <return_input>
0x080483f2 <main+8>:  mov  $0x0,%eax
0x080483f7 <main+13>: pop  %ebp
0x080483f8 <main+14>: ret
```

We can overwrite the saved return address with the address of the call to `return_input()`

```
$ printf
"AAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCCDDDDDD\xed\x83\x04\x08" | ./overflow
AAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCCDDDDDDí
AAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCCDDDDDDò
```

So this causes our input to be printed twice. However, I wasn't prompted for input a second time. Shouldn't the second call to `return_input()` result in a second call to `gets()`?

Comment: You are providing it with 10As, 10Bs, 10Cs, 6Ds, then 4 characters that represent where you want the stack pointer to go?  Isn't that exactly enough to fill the 30 char array up without spilling it over onto the stored return address?

Comment: @Akron, yes you're right. I posted what the book had but when I did this on my own machine it looked more like:
    `$ printf 'AAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCCDDDDDDDDDD\x8f\x05\x40\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00' | ./overflow
    AAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCCDDDDDDDDDD@
    AAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCCDDDDDDDDDD�@
    Bus error`

Answer (score 0):

This probably has to do with what gets() reads from stdin.

Slightly altered version of your program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int n = 1;

void return_input(void)
{
    char array[30];
    gets (array);
    printf("%s\n", array);
    if (n--) return_input();
}

int main(void)
{
    return_input();
    return 0;
}
```

If I just run it, I can type in 2 short strings (each followed by the Enter key), like so:

```
C:\gets.exe
qwe
qwe
123
123
```

And here both qwe and 123 get repeated on the screen (first time when I type them, second, when they get printed).

When I pipe programs input on Windows with the echo command, I get the following without a chance to enter the second string, gets() somehow manages to obtain garbage as input when it's called second time:

```
C:\echo qwe|gets.exe
qwe
№  ☺
```

So, something is wrong in how gets() reads piped input and that has nothing to do with stack overflows.